# Regular expression grep -r 'emm*[a-f].[^ta]$'

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I've been asking 1 hour ago a similar question  about regular expression using the grep command, pardon me if the prefered choice would have been to post in the same thread, if this is the case I would do so next time.

It might seems like basic synthax, but I'm trying to understand how regular expression recognition pattern works and the results I get seems to be contradicting the manual I'm reading about them ( I'm most likely not interpreting the material properly).

A  files contains the following list of words:

```
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ cat MySQLServ
remembré
emmuré
emmené
dilemmes
jumeaux
écrémage
emmena
emmailloter
flemmard
```

The following command gives the output

```
mael@mael-HP:~/repertoireVide$ grep -r 'emm*[a-f].[^ta]$'
MySQLServ:remembré
MySQLServ:emmené
MySQLServ:flemmard
```

I'm wondering why `grep` is not matching the word 'emmailloter', since 'emmailloter':

1. contains 'em'
2. contains a caracter between [a-f] afterwards : 'a'
3. 'i' fulfills the '.' component
4. does not end with either the caracter 't' or 'a'

Thanks.

Comment: They are different questions, so should remain separate. However I would recommend finding a good reg ex practice program or web site, and practice practice practice. Start with the basics `.`, `*`, `+`, `?`, then add `^` and `$`, then add more.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Note that most _websites_ that provides regular expression tests implements Perl-like regular expressions and not POSIX regular expressions.  GNU `grep` understands these with `-P`, but if you want portability, POSIX basic and extended regular expressions are more often used with Unix command line tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word `emmailloter` contains much more than `i` between the bits matched by `[a-f]` and `[^ta]$`.  The `.` pattern only ever matches a single character, so if you want to match multiple characters between `emma` and `r` at the end, you will have to allow for multiple characters:

```
emm*[a-f]..*[^ta]$
```

With `grep -E` (enabling extended regular expressions), `..*` could be written `.+`, i.e. "match at least one character". The expression `..*` reads as "match a character, and then possibly more characters".  In the same way, `emm*` could be replaced by `em+`, i.e. "`e` followed by at least one `m`" if using `grep -E`.

This would match the string

```
blop-emmmmmmmmma-blarg-b
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     1111111111233333334

1: emm*
2: [a-f]
3: ..*
4: [^ta]$
```

(the matching part indicated by the `^` characters above), for example, and also `emmailloter`:

```
emmailloter
^^^^^^^^^^^
11123333334
```

Testing:

```
$ grep -E 'emm*[a-f].+[^ta]$' MySQLServ
remembré
emmené
emmailloter
flemmard
```

Note that for the word `remembré`, the match will be

```
remembré
 ^^^^^^^
 1123334
```

not

```
remembré
   ^^^^^
   11234
```

One way to *visualise* the matches using `sed`:

```
$ sed -n -E 's/(emm*)([a-f])(.+)([^ta]$)/(\1)(\2)(\3)(\4)/p' MySQLServ
r(em)(e)(mbr)(é)
(emm)(e)(n)(é)
(emm)(a)(illote)(r)
fl(emm)(a)(r)(d)
```

This will only print matching lines, with each matched part of the regular expression in parentheses. This also assumes that you are using a `sed` implementation that can be used to match French characters and that the locale environment variables are properly set up for doing that.

Compare this with what your original expression produces:

```
$ sed -n -E 's/(emm*)([a-f])(.)([^ta]$)/(\1)(\2)(\3)(\4)/p' MySQLServ
rem(em)(b)(r)(é)
(emm)(e)(n)(é)
fl(emm)(a)(r)(d)
```

Comment: I'd add that the author's doubt probably comes from thinking of * as the shell glob operator. On regular expressions * (and other count operators such as + and ?) always apply to the previous match expression.

Comment: @Spidey, except that here it seems more like that they were expecting the dot `.` to match multiple characters (namely the `illote` in `emmailloter`)